# My app icon is showing Blur

Tags: icon, blur, applications

I am a fresher UI/UX designer.
My APP icon is **showing blur** and I am using photoshop 72 resolution and please tell me about android & ios icon measurement, Resolution and size.

Comment: Digital mediums disregard PPI/DPI o setting resolution value of the image fdoes not mean anything.

Answer (score -1):

Android and iOS both require your icon to be in various sizes to handle different end-devices. You can refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size) for android, or [this](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/) for iOS.

Ideally, you should create an icon at 300 dpi and a size larger than what you would require. (like 400x400)

You can then use one of the many freely available online tools to generate (downsize) your icon to the Android/iOS sizes.

Example, for iOS, you can use:

> http://appicon.build/

Comment: but I want to know about  icon resolution and quality. I have photoshop and illustrator both software.bt my icon is show blur.

Comment: A size of 1024x1024 pixels at a resolution of 72dpi should be a good starting point. You can then use this image and scale down for ldpi, mdpi, etc.

Comment: Thanks Aldo can u tell me about icon size and best software for icon.